# WebDriver - How to make the webdriver to wait until text displayed (without using locator)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have performed an action on `WebDriver` (Say, I clicked a button), resultant is a text will display on page.

We do not know locator element for the text, but we do know what text will display.

Please suggest a way to wait for the text to display.

I have come across `WebDriverWait`, but it requires `WebElement` to wait for text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go for xpath text based search. It allows you to find an element based on the text

```
// with * we are doing tag indepenedent search. If you know the tag, say it's a `div`, then //div[contains(text(),'Text To find')] can be done
By byXpath = By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Text To find')]"); 
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byXpath));
```

Comment: Hi Saifur, From your example how to detect if text is not displayed after 10 seconds

Comment: It will throw NoSuchElement exception if not found in 10s. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

WebDriverWait can be used even if you don't know the exact element. If the expected text only has 1 occurrence on the page, you can reach it through an Xpath like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, numberOfSeconds);    
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'my text')]")));
```

Comment: Why does the number of seconds need to be specified if we're telling the web driver to wait until a condition has been fulfilled?

Comment: @PaulChrisJones To prevent the code from waiting for the condition forever if the condition is never satisfied (say page failed to load). If after `numberOfSeconds` the condition hasn't been satisfied, `wait.until()` will throw

Answer (score 0):

For waiting text to be displayed in element:

```
private ExpectedCondition elementTextDisplayed(WebElement element, String text) {
        return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return element.getText().equals(text);
            }
        };
    }

 protected void waitForElementTextDisplayed(WebElement element, String text) {
        wait.until(elementTextDisplayed(element, text));
    }
```

or

```
public void waitUntilTextToBePresentInElement(WebElement element, String text){
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element, text));
}
```